# How to rename the WordPress wp-login.php running on IIS6?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, security, installation, iis

My Windows 2003 VPS recently hang due to bots hammering my WordPress login php non-stop for hours (determined from IIS6 logs).  This caused MySQL to use up all the allocated 1G RAM.  After resetting my VM, I quickly renamed wp-login.php to prevent my server from crashing again.

As per standard practice to rename the administrator username and admin login folders/paths of newly installed web applications, right after I installed my WP in June for the first time, I had tried to rename wp-admin folder, but failed.  I added Windows authentication to wp-admin in hope that this will help improve security, however, as it has been proved, this didn't prevent a DDOS like attack on wp-login.php.

For the time being, I'll have to rename it back to the original wp-login.php should I need to login.  Is there a way to permanently rename wp-login.php and have it function at the same time?  I've installed the [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) to allow IIS6 to support htaccess to some extent.

So far, the articles I found on the Internet are for Apache and for changing the admin username and password (one website even suggested using a password that is at least 30 characters long!).

**EDIT:**

I removed anonymous access for wp-login.php also, enabled Windows authentication and then diverted the Custom Error page for "HTTP 401.2 - Unauthorized" error to a blank HTM file.  I don't know if this method can fool the botnet but when tested with curl.exe, if the user is unauthenticated, a blank page will appear.

**EDIT:**

The above method proves to be ineffective.  :(  The botnet came back and attacked my protected wp-login.php.  I've renamed wp-login.php, let's see what happens now.

Comment: There's a [discussion going on](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Detecting-the-present-botnet-attacks-td41785.html) at [wp-hackers], maybe you'll find useful info. The related column here at the right has [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6415/12615).

Comment: @brasofilo Yes, I saw that, but please correct me if I'm wrong, but there isn't anyhing that will protect or rename the login.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post a while back, this is a quick and dirty hack to make hackers think your wp-login.php is a 404 page. http://dave.kz/hide-your-wp-login-page-from-hackers/.

(From blog post) Basically, I've added...

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 File Not Found");
```

to the top of the wp-login.php page. Hopefully the attacker is looking for a 200 HTTP response.

In addition you could do something like...

```
if(!isset($_GET['allow']) || $_GET['allow']!='true'){
    echo "Sorry, you need to use the magic URL to login.";
    die();
}
```

again, at the top of wp-login.php. This method would require you to go to http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?allow=true

Comment: Thank you for the link, are we able to find out if this method works?

Comment: David, please don't post links only. If the link disappears it makes the question useless and it's hard to maintain working links on that many pages. Please rework your answer.

Comment: @Joshua, it's impossible to tell if this is going to work. It depends how smart the attackers are. If their script looks at the HTTP request code, this should be pretty effective.