# How to change the login-URL with function.php?

Tags: login

I would to change the login URL of my site from http://example.com/wp-admin to http://example.com/example.
I don't wanna use a plugin for do that, so can I do that from function.php ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to rename or hide wp-login.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/is-there-any-way-to-rename-or-hide-wp-login-php)

Comment: note that despite first appearances this provides no security benefits and can also introduce compatibility issues

Comment: I would no prefer to do that with the .htaccess how suggested in the @PimSchaaf 's answer

Comment: @TomJNowell so? what you suggest?

Comment: don't try to hide `wp-admin` or `wp-login.php`, wordpress.com doesn't and it serves billions of visitors each day. If you're worried about people trying to abuse your login form there are well known solutions that are far more effective, 2 factor authentication, strong passwords, and plugins that limit login attempts. Even if you moved the login URL, people can use the built in shortcuts at `/login` and be redirected there, or bypass it completely. Most attempts to guess aren't even humans and they don't even check if you're a WP site, it's fire and forget

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to design a login page without the use of a plugin. Simply follow these simple steps to construct a login page using a template or a shortcode, both of which are discussed in this post.

[Create Login Page In WordPress Without Using Plugin](https://njengah.com/create-login-page-wordpress-without-plugin/)